# How can I use a method on every instance of a single class?

Tags: python, class, oop, object, tkinter

I have a tkinter-based GUI with many instances of a class grouped into a `ttk.LabelFrame`. The class inherits from `ttk.Frame`, and are placed in the `LabelFrame` using `.grid()`.  The `LabelFrame` also contains `ttk.Labels`.

Please see this very simplified example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class MyClass(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
    def MyMethod(self):
        print(tk.Widget.winfo_name(self))

root = tk.Tk()
frame = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="frame")
label = ttk.Label(frame, text="label")
class1 = MyClass(frame)
class2 = MyClass(frame)

print("class.MyMethod() calls:")
class1.MyMethod()
class2.MyMethod()

print("\ntkinter.Widget.nwinfo_children(frame):")
childlist = tk.Widget.winfo_children(frame)
print(childlist)
```

The output looks like this:

```
class.MyMethod() calls:
49250736
49252752

tkinter.Widget.nwinfo_children(frame):
[<tkinter.ttk.Label object .49250672.49252880>,
<__main__.MyClass object .49250672.49250736>,
<__main__.MyClass object .49250672.49252752>]
```

I want to do it something like:

```
for child in childlist:
    child.MyMethod()
```

Which doesn't work because of the labels. Or maybe:

```
for child in childlist:
    {if this is a MyClass instance}:
        child.MyMethod()
```

But I don't know if this is going in the right direction.

Is there a clean way to do what I want?

Comment: its not worth an answer `if isinstance(child,MyClass):` is what you want i think

Comment: an alternative would be `getattr(child,"MyMethod",lambda:1)()` that might actually be better

Comment: FWIW you can do `self.winfo_name()` rather than `tk.Widget.winfo_name(self)`

Comment: @martineau: you're correct, I was thinking of something else during a difficulty I had while manipulating dynamic library loading and class instanciations... I will edit my comment accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, @JoranBeasley! That's just what I'm looking for. I hate it when I miss the easy ones :)

Comment: Thanks to you, too, @BryanOakley :) That expanded my understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's @Joran Beasley's comment, fleshed-out:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class MyClass(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
    def MyMethod(self):
        print(self.winfo_name())

root = tk.Tk()
frame = ttk.LabelFrame(root, text="frame")
label = ttk.Label(frame, text="label")
class1 = MyClass(frame)
class2 = MyClass(frame)

print("class.MyMethod() calls:")
class1.MyMethod()
class2.MyMethod()

print("\ntkinter.Widget.nwinfo_children(frame):")
childlist = tk.Widget.winfo_children(frame)
print(childlist)

for child in childlist:
    if isinstance(child, MyClass):
        child.MyMethod()
```

Output:

```
class.MyMethod() calls:
!myclass
!myclass2

tkinter.Widget.nwinfo_children(frame):
[<tkinter.ttk.Label object .!labelframe.!label>, <__main__.MyClass object .!labelframe.!myclass>, <__main__.MyClass object .!labelframe.!myclass2>]
!myclass
!myclass2
```

Or perhaps a little more succinctly:

```
my_class_children = [child for child in tk.Widget.winfo_children(frame)
                        if isinstance(child, MyClass)]
print(my_class_children)
for child in my_class_children:
    child.MyMethod()
```

Output:

```
[<__main__.MyClass object .!labelframe.!myclass>, <__main__.MyClass object .!labelframe.!myclass2>]
!myclass
!myclass2
```

Comment: Thanks for writing this up and fleshing it out.  Your "succinct" example serves me very well. :)

Comment: bitsmack: Happy to hear it helped. Note, too, things could be even more terse by using `all(child.MyMethod() is None for child in my_class_children)` although it's slightly misleading since the return value of `all()` is ignored.